# C++ truncation error?

Tags: c++, formula, truncation

I am learning C++ and came upon this problem while trying to use a formula to calculate the current.

[image: formula]

And I got: `0.628818` where the answer should be:

> f=200 Hz
>
> R=15 Ohms
>
> C=0.0001 (100µF)
>
> L=0.01476 (14.76mH)
>
> E = 15 V
>
> Answer:  I = 0.816918A (calculated)

Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    const double PI = 3.14159;
    double r = 15;
    double f = 200;
    double c = 0.0001;
    double l = 0.01476;
    double e = 15;

    double ans = e / std::sqrt(std::pow(r, 2) + (std::pow(2 * PI*f*l - (1.0 / 2.0 * PI*f*c), 2)));

    std::cout << "I = " << ans << "A" << std::endl;
}
```

I have read about truncation errors and tried to use 1.0/2.0 but doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Why use `1.0 / 2.0` instead of just `0.5`?

Comment: `const double PI = 3.14159;` will make funny looking circles, and is a bit of a waste of a `double`. And please put the formula in the question: links decay.

Comment: `(1.0 / 2.0 * PI*f*c)` should be `(1.0 / (2.0 * PI*f*c))`.

Comment: Never use PI as you do. There is a loss of precision here; see `<cmath>` and the constant M_PI

Comment: @DanielLangr is right. Moreover, you imported math, why don't you use `M_PI` instead of `const double PI = 3.14159;'`?

Comment: Try calculating `PI` to maximum precision, such as `acos(-1.0)` (one of several alternatives).   `pow(r,2)` is more simply expressed as `r*r`.   `1.0/2.0` may be expressed more readably, and with same precision, as `0.5`.

Comment: @Bentoy13 - `M_PI` is not actually standard C++ (`<cmath>`) nor is it in standard C (`<math.h>`).   It is an extension, and not all libraries support it.

Comment: @DanielLangr I think that's it. I get `I = 0.816917A`.

Comment: Truncation error refers to using only the first N terms of an infinite series to estimate a value.

Comment: If you believe there are "truncation errors", why not simply break up lines like this: `ans = e / sqrt(pow(r, 2) + (pow(2 * PI*f*l - (1.0 / 2.0 * PI*f*c), 2)) ` into multiple lines to isolate where the truncation errors occur?  This is worthy of a downvote due to lack of research.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Research what "trucation error" means. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_error

Comment: This is not a truncation error, nor is it a loss of precision. Fiddling with the definition of pi won't help. As @DanielLangr points out, the problem is that the code does not correctly implement the formula.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Hey, I knew that. :-) I cast some pearls anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Truncation error refers to using only the first N terms of an infinite series to estimate a value. So the answer to your question is "No."  You might find the following to be of some interest however....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>  
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T fsqr(T x) { return x * x; }

// Numerically stable and non-blowuppy way to calculate
// sqrt(a*a+b*b)
template<typename T>
T pythag(T a, T b) {
    T absA = fabs(a);
    T absB = fabs(b);
    if (absA > absB)
    {
        return absA*sqrt(1.0 + fsqr(absB / absA));
    } else if (0 == absB) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return absB*sqrt(1.0 + fsqr(absA / absB));
    }
}
int main () {

double e, r, f, l, c, ans;

const double PI = 3.14159265358972384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170;
cout << "Insert value for resistance: " << endl;
cin >> r ;

cout << "Insert value for frequency: " << endl;
cin >> f;

cout << "Insert value for capacitance: " << endl;
cin >> c;

cout << "Insert value for inductance: " << endl;
cin >> l;

cout << "Insert value for electromotive force (voltage): " << endl;
cin >> e;

ans = e / pythag(r, 2*PI*f*l - (1/(2*PI*f*c)) );

cout << "I = " << ans << "A" << endl;

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Just kidding about all that PI.

Comment: So I can understand that you're simplifying one of the terms out of the square root. But I don't understand how this improves the accuracy of the calculation. Can you help explain?

Comment: When one of the terms, a or b, is much smaller in magnitude than the other, the naive way, `sqrt(a*a + b*b)` may have significant round-off error. Always try to avoid adding or substracting numbers that differ greatly in magnitude. In pythag(), we test which is larger, and calculate accordingly.

Comment: @JonathanMee - Understand?

Comment: Ugh. Yes when I can change my mind to think about the fact that floating point numbers have only limited precision I do :(

Comment: @JonathanMee - Also, sqrt is numerically unstable near zero. Better to change things around so you're taking sqrt of a number bigger than 1.

Comment: Does your `pythag()` function provide stronger guarantee of precision than is required of `std::hypot()`?

Comment: @TobySpeight I wrote pythag over 15 years ago. I didn't know about hypot until now. I would be surprised if they are not identical

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is multiplying ½ by πfC instead of dividing, here:

```
    (1.0 / 2.0 * PI*f*c)
```

This sort of problem is best avoided by using suitable named values (that also allows you to use faster and more precise `x*x` instead of `std::pow(x,2)`).

You can also remove some of that arithmetic by using the standard hypotenuse function instead of squaring and sqrting inline:

```
double ans = e / std::hypot(r, (2*PI*f*l - 0.5/PI/f/c));
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    static constexpr double PI = 4 * std::atan(1);
    double r = 15;              // ohm
    double f = 200;             // hertz
    double c = 0.0001;          // farad
    double l = 0.01476;         // henry
    double e = 15;              // volt

    double current = e / std::hypot(r, (2 * PI*f*l -  0.5/PI/f/c));

    std::cout << "I = " << current << "A" << std::endl;
}
```